# Why is my javascript ajax code returning undefined for the XMLHttpRequest GET response? - running in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to perform a GET, parse the GET for a json object, and then send that object back in a POST. However, the GET appears to not return anything (prints undefined to the console) What am I missing here?
Running in Node.js

```
const XMLHttpRequest = 
require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
let response, jsonObject;

// perform GET
http.open("GET", url);
http.send();

// save the text
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        response = this.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
}

// parse json object
console.log(response);
jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(jsonObject);

//Perform POST
http.open("POST", url);
http.send(jsonObject);
```

Comment: While I understand the importance of knowing the underlying code/technology of making requests in node.js, save yourself the headache and use the fetch API. There's a nice little NPM package that ports the web standard to node.js

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following help at mozilla.org at URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest. You can try adding an event listener like described to see the progress of the response and then bind a function to handle the response. That way you know what is going on with your call for asyn AJAX request. - Shalu Chawla